# texstudio installation problem

Tags: installing, texstudio

I 'm using Windows 10 Pro and I want to install TeXstudio 2.12.16.

I download the `exe` file from [here](https://texstudio.org/), I start installation, but a few time later I get this error message:

[image]

If I select "*Ματαίωση*" (cancel) and then the "*Show details*" button I get this:

> Output folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\texstudio Can't write:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\texstudio\texstudio.exe

I changed the security of the target folder (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4C2wqiUfGTg)), but nothing has happened.

What should I do?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Just as a test, can you try to install somewhere in your home folder (e.g. on your desktop) where you know that you have all the necessary permissions to write files?

Comment: @gigi , thanks for your answer. I tried to install it here *C:\Users\HP 250\Desktop\test\texstudio* and everything is OK.

Comment: Ok, this means that it is probably a problem of permissions. Can you show a screenshot of the permissions of the `Program Files (x86)` folder and of the `texstudio` folder inside of it?

Comment: If you right click on the folder and open properties, is there some list with attributes, e.g. something like "Read Only", "Writing Permission" etc.? (they are probably called something else in english, I just tried to translate from my native language)

Comment: I thought to restart my pc and I retried to install the program. Now everything is ok. I didn't do anything, except that (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4C2wqiUfGTg) I said to my question. I don't know what happen... Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You should run the installer as administrator.  right click on the installer then choose "Run as administrator".

Comment: The problem fixed itself! I do not know how... Maybe your advise solve this problem, but without problem I can' check it... Also I 'll have it to my mind! Thanks for your answer!